# How do I send data using JSON as output format?

Tags: 7, webforms

There are separate web forms created on the basis of the Webform module (Drupal 7), sending by default goes to the required e-mail. Everything is within the module.

In addition, there was a need to send the data of the webform application (field) to various CRM (custom) based on JSON.

#### Request format

```
{
    "aCode": "zzz",
    "importdata": {
        "id": "zzz",
        "user_data": {
            "name": "zzz",
        },
        "contact": {
            "phone": "zzz",
        }
    }
}
```

How do I properly implement this functionality?

**Process:**

External url for accepting JSON lead requests (example): http://example-server.com:8083/api/submit

After the webform has been filled in, it is necessary to automatically **send the field data in the raw postdata format** to the external CRM with the JSON request format specified above in the code.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you gave a quick description of what you want to achieve, but you didn't say what exactly you don't understand in the way to achieve it. Is there anything in particular you want to ask? Asking how to _properly_ implement a functionality is quite broad. At least, describe what you though to do, and we can tell you what is wrong in the way you think to implement it.

Comment: In this functionality, you should only send Webform fields to a third-party CRM in JSON format.

The main question is how to make sure that the usual text fields of a particular Webform are converted to the required JSON format (specified above) and sent to the external system.

Comment: @alex you got me confused when you mentioned "Request Format" above the JSON snippet. I was of the impression that you would get a request from CRM in that format and you would respond in JSON. After you edited your question it seems that the format above is the format in which you need to send the data to the CRM.

Comment: I tried to add all the data so that it was clear what mechanism of work is needed.